# how can i list array that is inside another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I'm processing a form onchange event, in this form i got a few inputs, selects and textareas, I was wondering if something like this would work for grabbing the input values in this form

```
var lat = {
    listen: function () {
        var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        var elements = [input,select,textarea];
        console.log(elements.length);
        for (var a = 0 ; a < elements.length ; a++) {
            for ( var b = 0 ; elements[a].length ; b++) {
                console.log(elements[a][b].value);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: yes i did, it doesnt work, and yes i'm calling lat.listen();

Comment: FYI, an alternative would be `document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea")`, which will give you a flat list, though not grouped like you have them..

Comment: hmmm that querySelectorAll(); should workout fine i think, will try! TY

Comment: Typo: `elements[a].length` should be `b < elements[a].length`. Fix that and it works.

Comment: Rhumborl, i really appreciate your sarcasm, seems to be working out for you

Comment: @brunobliss Don't think he was being sarcastic. We just want to know exactly what doesn't work.  Does console.log() not work?  Do the loops not work?  Do the document.get...() method calls not work?  There are few a moving parts in your code, and we just want to know what ones are not working specifically.

Comment: @squint, thanks man! well spotted

Answer (score 2):

Get silly wit it

http://jsfiddle.net/jkabxpkw/1/

```
var values = document.getElementById('form') ? (function (array) {
    var elements = document.getElementById('form').children;
    for (var element in elements) {
        if (elements.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
            if (elements[element].value) {
                array.push(elements[element].value);
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}([])) : null;
```

Comment: thank you guys for the answers, however, my logic was right i was just missing a lesser than sign for the loop to go through

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can map and reduce like so:

```
var elements = [
  document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
  document.getElementsByTagName('select'),
  document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')
].map(function(i) {
  // converts the HTMLCollection elements to an array
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(i);
}).reduce(function(result, value) {
  return result.concat(value);
}, []).forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
});
```